# SPRING - what is the meaning of ORIGIN in CORS

Tags: java, spring, browser, cors

I don't know what is the meaning ORIGIN in web development, and what is the meaning in spring framework and what I should make in origin attribute in [this example](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) below :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
    // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
 }
```

what is the meaning of **"http://domain2.com"**, and what are the mechanism of CORS in server side and client side ( i don't understand the example of bank account above in the link).

thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not really Spring related. Basically you put in the origins array all the domains you are going to be accesing your spring backend from. If you don't want any hassle, just set it to `*` to allow all origins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CrossOrigin with no arguments means your controller will accept all requests. 
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600) means it will only accepts requests comming from this url : "http://domain2.com"

So for example, if your client is on server "hhtp://localhost:8080" and he sends request to your service GET /account/5 
your service will reject that.